# NHibernate order by a property of bag

Tags: nhibernate

In my project I am using NHibernate as persistence framework and, by database, I have a table called User and a child one called recipe (all are mapped correctly in a separate hbm.xml file).
This is the xml of "User":

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="MyProject.Engine.Domain.User,MyProject.Engine" table="Users" lazy="true">
    <id name="UserID" column="UserID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Firstname" column="Firstname" type="string" not-null="true" length="255" />
    <property name="Lastname" column="Lastname" type="string" not-null="true" length="255" />
    <property name="Email" column="Email" type="string" not-null="true" length="255" />
    <property name="Phone" column="Phone" type="string" not-null="true" length="30" />
    <property name="Birthday" column="Birthday" type="date" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="Address" column="Address" type="string" not-null="true" length="255" />
    <property name="City" column="City" type="string" not-null="true" length="50" />
    <property name="Zipcode" column="Zipcode" type="int" not-null="true" length="32" />
    <property name="Province" column="Province" type="string" not-null="true" length="30" />
    <one-to-one name="Receipt" cascade="all" property-ref="UserID" class="MyProject.Engine.Domain.Receipt,MyProject.Engine"  />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Receipt object have a property called Amount and I would order by record using that property. As now, I am only able to order by record by using the "User" entity (es: Email, Phone).
If I try to use a property of linked entity I got an error. How could I reference it?

This is my method to get and order my record:

```
public PagedList<User> GetAll(int pageIndex, int pageSize, string orderBy, string orderByAscOrDesc)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var users = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (User));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
                users.AddOrder(orderByAscOrDesc.ToLower() == "asc" ? Order.Asc(orderBy) : Order.Desc(orderBy));
            return users.PagedList<User>(session, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You will need to do it client side instead. 
See related answer here :
[NHibernate: how to sort a collection by a property of a referenced entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179636/nhibernate-how-to-sort-a-collection-by-a-property-of-a-referenced-entity)